# Playing shot .wav file on mobile device Android (PHP,HTML,JS)

Tags: android, audio, mobile, wav, playing

I need to play short .wav sound on mobile site (Android tablet).

I have tried:
`<embed src="sound.wav" autostart="true" loop="false" width="0" height="0"></embed>`

It is working on PC/MAC but doesn't on iOS/Android.

Is it possible to play sound on mobile devices (like Facebook sound message)?

Comment: Have you find a solution the last 2 years? :P